# How to replicate a list to the length of list2?

Tags: python, list, iterator

I have list1 of a certain length and list2 of a certain length. Let's say:

```
list1 = [32, 345, 76, 54]

list2 = [43, 65, 76, 23, 12, 23, 44]
```

I need to make list1 loop back around until it is the same length as list2. Or, if list1 is longer, I need it to cut down to the length of list2. For the example above, I am looking to make:

```
list1 = [32, 345, 76, 54, 32, 345, 76]
```

It doesn't necessarily have to remain list1. It can be a new list I just need the same values from list1 looped back around a certain number of times. How do I go about doing this? I'm fairly new to python and I haven't been able to find anything that works.

Answer (score 6):

Get to know the wonderful `itertools` module!

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

result = list(islice(cycle(list1), len(list2)))
```

If all you need is to iterate both list "together", this is even easier:

```
for x, y in zip(cycle(list1), list2):
    print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle

new_list1 = [element for element, index in zip(cycle(list1), range(len(list2)))]
new_list1
```

Output:

```
[32, 345, 76, 54, 32, 345, 76]
```

Comment: Why the `index`? And if so, why not `enumerate`?

Comment: Because `zip` will stop yielding values when the shortest of the iterables passed to it is exhausted. `islice` is better, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pure Python:

```
list1 = [32, 345, 76, 54]

list2 = [43, 65, 76, 23, 12, 23, 44]

l1, l2 = (len(list1) ,len(list2)) 
diff = (l2- l1) % l2
times = (l2 - l1) // l2
list1 = list1 * (times+1) + list1[:diff]
print(list1)
```

Result:

```
[32, 345, 76, 54, 32, 345, 76]
```

An alternative would be:

```
list1 = [32, 345, 76, 54]

list2 = [43, 65, 76, 23, 12, 23, 44]

times = len(list1) + (len(list2) - len(list1))
list1 = [list1[i%len(list1)] for i in range(times)]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more *verbose* solution using `itertools.cycle` which others have already demonstrated. It might be easier to understand this way.

```
target = len(list2) # the target length we want to hit
curr = 0 # keep track of the current length of output
out = [] # our output list
inf = cycle(list1) # an infinite generator that yields values

while curr < target:
    out.append(next(inf))
    curr += 1

print(out)
# [32, 345, 76, 54, 32, 345, 76]
```